# MARS, MIPS assembler, linking two files together?

Tags: linker, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I have a quick question. I am using MARS assembler (programming in the MIPS instruction set) and I have two MIPS files. One file contains my main method to be run and it calls a function in the other file. My function has the **.globl** directive before it, but every time I try and compile my program it says

> Symbol "print_hex" not found in symbol table.

Here is a screen shot for more context:
[image]

The label *print_hex* is located in the file called print_hex.s.

[image]

How can I link these two files together? Lastly, how can I tell MARS to call a specific label at the start of execution, for example I want it to call *main*.

Comment: Rather than screenshots you should take the text you are interested in showing us and put it in the body of the Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Put the files in the same directory
2. Enable the MARS option `Settings->Assemble all files in directory`
3. Assemble the file you want to start execution at.

And then all the files in the directory should get assembled and linked together.

To always have execution start at your main label, you can enable `Settings->Initialize program counter to global 'main'`.